# Passing a string as argument in jdbcTemplate.queryForObject

Tags: java, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

I am trying to pass a string as 3rd argument in jdbcTemplate.queryForObject function but am getting error 'method queryForObject is not applicable for the arguments'. Below is my piece of code.

```
String twoYearBeforeDate = adhpDetailUtil.getDateBeforeTwoYear();
        final String QUERY = "select * " +  "from gfc.LSI_ELGBLTY " + "where INSURANCE_ID = ? and " + "SYS_CD = ? and " + "LSI_CNCLN_DT >= ?";
        Object[] params = new Object[]  {
                request.getInsuranceId(),request.getSystemId()};
            String ids = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(QUERY, params, twoYearBeforeDate, new AdhpDetailsRequestMapper());
```

How can i pass the string 'twoYearBeforeDate' with the objects as the third param to query. It will work if i change the type of 'twoYearBeforeDate' to int but i need to pass this as a string varaible. can anyone have an idea on this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Object[] params = new Object[]  {
            request.getInsuranceId(),
            request.getSystemId(), 
            twoYearBeforeDate};
String ids = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(QUERY, params, new AdhpDetailsRequestMapper());
```